# Except block not executing

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as ptl
import investpy as invpy

stock_data = invpy.stocks.get_stocks("Brazil")
ticker_list = []
for i in range(len(stock_data["symbol"])):
    string_ticker = str(stock_data["symbol"][i])
    ticker = f"{string_ticker}.SA"
    ticker_list.append(ticker)
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in ticker_list:
    try:
        data = yf.download(ticker, period = "max")
    except:
        ticker_list.remove(ticker)
```

I'm capturing all the tickers listed on the Brazilian stock exchange with investpy and because some symbols are delisted or give errors when running the finance.download function, I have to do a try and except block. But, for some reason, when the errors occur it doesn't delete the ticker that gave me the error. What I'm doing wrong and how can i make it work ?

Comment: As an aside, use `except Exception`, not `except` (so that you don't catch things like `KeyboardInterrupt`), but better yet, only catch the exception you *expect* will be raised.  Also, don't remove items from the list you are iterating over, or the iterator will skip items.

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/main/yfinance/multi.py) doesn't appear to raise an Exception of any kind. You can validate that the size of the data is `0` to get around this. However, there *is* a bug that you will introduce.

You are modifying your list during iteration, which can cause the place you are pointing at in the list to change.

Try one of the following approaches:

1. Creating a `new_ticker_list` with only tickers that download:

```py
new_ticker_list = []

for ticker in ticker_list:
    data = yf.download(ticker, period = "max")
    
    if not data:
        continue
    else:
        new_ticker_list.append(ticker)
```

2. Iterating indirectly using an index:

```py
idx = 0

while idx < len(ticker_list):
    data = yf.download(ticker, period = "max")
    
    if not data:
        _ = ticker_list.pop(idx)
    else:
        idx += 1
```

Comment: You need'nt to increment `idx` instead of `i` ?